# ubuntu 15.10 default editor doesn't work for sftp remote files

Tags: 15.10, default-programs

I installed a different text-editor in Ubuntu 15.10 but nautilus (and nemo) still open files with gedit...
In the "file properties" -> "Open with" there is already setted as default.

I'm trying to open sftp files from nautilus.

I already tried with leafpad but the result is exactly the same.

What I must do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For we it works when doing this:

1. right click on the file

[image: contextual menu]

2. choose "open with..." from the contextual menu
3. choose "other application"

[image: open with menu]

4. click on "View all applications" button
5. pick up Sublime Text

Does it works for you?

Another solution is to use the file property dialog box. Right click on the file, then property.
In the dialog box you can choose which program is associated with the file.

[image: image property open with tab]

Comment: Hi, i already do both. It works perfectly for locale files, but with remote files always gedit... Till yesterday worked. Today the software updater updated lightdm